# Returning an object in an function expression - is null

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript.

I have this code...

```
var test = new function () {

    var vars = {
        $hub: null
    };

    var init = function () {
        vars.$hub = $.connection.blabla;
    };

    return {
        vars: vars,
        init: init,
        $hub: vars.$hub
    };

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    test.init();
    test.vars.$hub..... // Works perfecetly
    test.$hub..... // Doesn't work - test.$hub is null
});
```

I don't get why test.$hub is null when test.vars.$hub isn't null?

Thanks

Comment: The `init()` function updates the value of `vars.$hub` but that does not affect the `null` value returned when the `test` object was initially built.

Comment: The reason this is difficult to groc is because it really doesn't follow any best practice in writing JS Constructor functions. There are better ways to make this work the way you would expect to a certain extent. But as Pointy points out, order of operation matters. Your problem starts with assigning the return value of a constructor function. you might consider reading up on constructor functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Object directly with [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on $hub:

```js
var test = new function() {
  return {
    vars: {
        $hub: null
    },
    init: function () {
        this.vars.$hub = 'something';
    },  
    get $hub() {
      return this.vars.$hub;
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(test.$hub) // before init
    test.init();
    console.log(test.vars.$hub) // Works perfecetly
    console.log(test.$hub) // Works too!!!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect ... thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know the "getter".

Answer (score 0):

vars (and $hub: null) is defined within the scope of Function test whereas test.$hub is not defined.

If you wrote:

```
var test = new function () {

    var $hub = null;

    var vars = {
        $hub: null
    };

    var init = function () {
        vars.$hub = $.connection.blabla;
    };

    return {
        vars: vars,
        init: init,
        $hub: vars.$hub
    };

};
```

You can now access the value of `test.$hub` as `null`.

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for helping me out here. I need the "test.$hub" to be the object I created in the init function.